# return values from "map" & print them

Tags: dictionary, go, println

I am just trying to print the output of map function...

**Input:** "hello world"
**Output expected:** map['h': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 3, 'o': 2, 'r': 1, 'w': 1, 'd': 1, ' ': 1]
**My Code:**

```
package main

import "fmt"

/*
https://www.programmingexpert.io/programming-with-go/maps/practice-questions/1

*/
func main() {
    CharacterFrequency("hello world")

}

func CharacterFrequency(sentence string) map[rune]int {
    characters := map[rune]int{}
    // characters := make(map[rune]int)

    for _, char := range sentence {
        value, ok := characters[char]

        if !ok {
            characters[char] = 1
        } else {
            characters[char] = value + 1
        }
    }
    //fmt.Println(characters)
    //fmt.Printf("%c", characters)
    fmt.Printf("%c", map[rune]int)  // so here is where I am not getting proper values
    return characters
}
```

```
//fmt.Println(characters)
//fmt.Printf("%c", characters)
fmt.Printf("%c", map[rune]int)  // so here is where I am not getting proper values
```

**expecting:**
map['h': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 3, 'o': 2, 'r': 1, 'w': 1, 'd': 1, ' ': 1]

fmt.Println(characters) **gave me below**
map[32:1 100:1 101:1 104:1 108:3 111:2 114:1 119:1]

fmt.Printf("%c", characters) **gave me below**
map[ :☺ d:☺ e:☺ h:☺ l:♥ o:☻ r:☺ w:☺]

fmt.Printf("%c", map[rune]int) **blows up with**
".\10_go_map_dict_q1.go:29:19: map[rune]int (type) is not an expression"

Comment: Why is the question tagged `python`?

Comment: `rune` is an alias for `int32`. Either iterate over the map and format each key and value separately, or make a more convenient map from `map[string]int`

Comment: `fmt.Printf("%c", map[rune]int)` does not compile because `map[rune]int` is a type, not an expression.

Comment: so the "%c" is giving correct results, nothing pulls the right side of (characters) in the map?

Comment: @BigDog169: you have two different types which you want two different formatting verbs for, so you cannot use a single format for the entire map. The `rune` needs to be formatted as a character (`%c`) or as a string (`%q`), but the right side needs to be formatted as an integer (`%d`). There is no one-size-fits-all, so just loop over the values and format them each however you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    CharacterFrequency("hello world")
}

func CharacterFrequency(sentence string) map[string]int {
    characters := map[string]int{}
    for _, char := range sentence {
        characters[string(char)]++
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v", characters)
    // Output: map[ :1 d:1 e:1 h:1 l:3 o:2 r:1 w:1]
    return characters
}
```

Comment: this pattern is also often written as `characters[string(char)]++`

Comment: Good call, changing to that.